# Android scrollable table

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-tablelayout

How can I achieve to get this table scroll if content is too big horizontal and vertical?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/banner" />
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow
                  android:background="@drawable/standard"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="@string/rankColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/teamColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/matchesColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/winColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/drawColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/looseColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/winPercentColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/pointsColumnHeader"
                      android:layout_margin="6sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                  android:id="@+id/demoTextView"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to put the table into a ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/banner" />
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow
              android:background="@drawable/standard"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="@string/rankColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/teamColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/matchesColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/winColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/drawColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/looseColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/winPercentColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/pointsColumnHeader"
                  android:layout_margin="6sp"
                  android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_margin="6sp"
              android:textColor="@color/black"
              android:id="@+id/demoTextView"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: dont know why but its not showing my scrollbars. i cant scroll oltough i use this scrollview